# Sybase: Copying back to the same table with different ID

Tags: sql, select, insert, sybase

I have a table where I want to copy some data back to the same table with two columns getting changed:

e.g:

```
TableMusic

titleid   musicid  tap_id            value

1234         1      3                 this is music
1324         1      3                 this is music test
```

I want the titleid and the value to be written back to the same table with musicid=3

Here the indexed columns are titleid, musicid

I have done the following script but got an error: attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'tablemusic' with unique index 'pk_tablemusic'

```
insert into tablemusic (titleid, musicid, value )
  select titleid, 3, value
  from tablemusic
  where musicid=1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone come up with a clean script to get the job done.

following is an extract from my DB for one titleID:

```
titleid   musicid    tap_id              value

462847        1        3               this is my music value 
462847        2        1    
462847        3        1    
462847        4        1
```

this is the same for all titleid's. Now what I want to do is copy the value from musicid=1 to musicid=3 and also sometime change the tap_id to 3. I hope this is clear enough of what i want to achieve

Final Result want to achieve:

titleid       musicid      tap_id              value

```
462847        1        3               
462847        2        1    
462847        3        3               this is my music value 
462847        4        1
```

Comment: Seems correct so I would check you have no data with musicid=3 and the indexes are correct

Comment: @mark: I do have data with musicid=3, but it does have a different title id and a different tap_id. Now my aim here is to copy the title and value of musicid=1 to musicid=3.

Comment: the issue is that your code should work so some of the details you give are not correct

Comment: @mark: following is an extract from my DB for one titleID:           titleid<musicid<tap_id<value<
-----------<-----------<-----------<-----------<-----<
462847<1<3<this is my music value<
462847<2<1< <
462847<3<1< <
462847<4<1< <  this is the same for all titleid's. Now what I want to do is copy the value from musicid=1 to musicid=3 and also sometime change the tap_id to 3. I hope this is clear enough of what i want to achieve.

Comment: Your comment is unreadable - if more data edit the question -  I think I understand what you want. The code looks correct so there is some other problem and that will be the data structure e.g. indicies or the actual data

Comment: @Mark can you now check the above you can see a sample for one title id. Now each title id exists with 4 musicid's (1,2,3,4). Now what I want is to copy the value 'this is my music value' from musicid=1 to musicid=3 (titleid remains same when I do this copy)and sometimes copy this to musicid=3 and change the tap_id=3. Keeping in mind here that titleid and musicid are indexed columns. I hope I'm clear enough now.

Comment: That data makes it cleraer - you already have a row with key 462847 ,       3 what do you want do do with the data from 462847, 1 ? overwrite the value and tap_id already there or what?

Comment: Copy the value (i.e:this is my music value)of 462847, 1(musicid) to 462847, 3(musicid) and in some cases copy it to 432847, 3(musicid), 3(tap_id).

Comment: @mark: please see the post above, I have edited to show the final result I want to achieve

Comment: @mark: probably I believe I might have to use the update command instead of a the insert into. Can you please do me a query with the update command to achieve the above.

Comment: @mark I don't have any success in this so far, trying from long time, do you have any more suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is that some records exist so trying a simple insert duplicates the key and you get the error. What you have to do here is to break up the query into two prts

1. Update the rows with musicid = 3 that exist
2. Insert the rows where music id=3 does not exist

Comment: I need to go off - so I can't do the exact SQL yet

Comment: Thank mark, this was useful in thinking this problem other way round I have resolved it and will post my solution here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is script based on Mark's answer above with a few changes. Thanks MARK - You are my hero.

First I ran this script:

delete from tablemusic  where musicid=3

After the above I ran the following script:

insert into tablemusic (titleid, musicid, tap_id, value)
  select  titleid, 3, 3, value 
   from tablemusic
    where musicid=1

This give me the results I want to achieve as shown in the question above.

Comment: That will delete some recorsd where musicid=3 and where there is no musicid=1 is that what you want

Comment: yes, i first deleted with music id=3, then added it back changing the tap_id to 3. It is working the way I want